# How to add DoubleTap event to a control

Tags: c#, wpf, touch

I have a `ScatterView` in which I can add custom scatter view items. They are represented in a grid containing two viewbox:

- One for the custom shape
- One for a TextBlock (elmtNameTextBlock)

The TextBlock can be modified by double clicking on it: it opens a window with a simple TextBox which closes on "Enter" press and updates elmtNameTextBlock.

As my program has to be designed for surface. I have to handle a DoubleTap event for that. I saw two methods for that:

1. [DoubleTap Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.doubletap(v=vs.95).aspx)
2. [DoubleTapped Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.doubletapped?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)

I tried to add both event:

```
public event EventHandler<GestureEventArgs> DoubleTap;
```

and

```
public event DoubleTappedEventHandler DoubleTapped;
```

but my program cannot find `GestureEventArgs` while I have the correct namespace and `DoubleTappedEventHandler`.

Have I for only choice to handle the `DoubleTap` event manually ?

Comment: Are you sure your project is referencing the right DLL?  I've noticed that sometimes Microsoft has the code for the same namespace in more than one DLL.  Make sure your project references the right assemblies.

Comment: For the first example, it seems I need System.Windows.Input, System.Windows and I got them. I will try to handle it manually unfortunately.